# Ajax parsing response from http 409

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, error-handling, xmlhttprequest

Trying to parse out the message object using Ajax, but can not get a reference to messages.msg. It does display correctly using PostMan but can not get this message in Ajax.

PostMail handles the response correctly:

```
    {
       "httpStatusCode": 409,
       "httpStatus": "CONFLICT",
       "messages": {
           "msg": "ticket 1112 is owned by 2223"
    }
}
```

Ajax

```
fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
//fail(function(err) { did not work
        //console.log(err);    did not work
        //xhr.responseText;    did not work
        //var msg = $.parseJSON(err).msg;  did not work
        //alert(msg);   did not work
        var acc = []
        $.each(xhr, function(index, value) {
            acc.push(index + ': ' + value);
        });
        alert(JSON.stringify(acc));   //did not see any object which includes  response message
        console.log('FAIL');
    })
```

Done displays perfect for a 202 ACCEPTED

```
done(function(data, statusText, xhr) {
        console.log('SUCCESS');
        alert(data.messages.msg);
    })
```

Comment: could you add full code how you call fail and done methods

Comment: Had to catch 409, add to body and access in .fail var data = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);

Comment: catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body(ex.getResponseBodyAsString());

Answer (score 0):

Had to catch 409, and then add to body:
        catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) { 
        return

ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body(ex.getResponseBodyAsString()); –

Then access in .fail 
   var data = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);